# how can I recieve the value of 'nr_running' member of sturct rq(run queue) from user space

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

I want to write a program that shows the number of tasks in cpus' run queues at different times .

In order to do that I need somehow to have access from userspace to **nr_running** of **struct rq** of the cpus ( [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/sched.h?v=3.14) you can find **struct rq** and inside it **nr_running** source code inside the kernel)

Is there a  file/system call that can help me with that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from reading `/proc/loadavg`

```
$ cat /proc/loadavg
0.57 0.37 0.28 1/607 7856
```

In above 1 is representing `nr_running`

See source at http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/loadavg.c#L13

Comment: what does 607 represent? I want to be able to print nr_running of each cpu

Comment: @nadavgam: `nr_running()` is the sum of all cpu's nr_running value http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/core.c#L2667 I will research more, if there is a way to print for each cpu. 607 is nr_threads

Comment: maybe I can do that by creating a simple kernel module ?

Comment: @nadavgam unfortunately I am not expert at writing kernel modules, but I assume you could easily access that info from with in a kernel module

Comment: btw, why are you looking for per cpu runqueue?

Comment: for a project im doing , something to do with the scheduler load balancer